# How to work with apache Jmeter for login applications?

Tags: apache, cookies, authentication, jmeter

Hi I would like to test using Jmeter for my application which has login page. I am able to write Sample http request for login page which is working ( passing username and password as POST parameters).

But the another Sample  HttpRequest (home.do) is not working which is again redirecting to login page. I also added HttpCookieManager at Thread level. Not sure why the authentication is not carry forward to other pages, Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: why is the different between browser post and jmeter post? maybe you have missing parameter/header?

Comment: Do you have HttpHeaderManager?

Comment: yes i have not added HttpHeaderManager, Could you please tell me should i add it for Login request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your test doesn't work due to missing or incorrect [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations). The absolute majority of modern web applications use dynamic parameters for different reasons (client state tracking, security, etc.) so you need to setup your test plan like:

- Open Login Page (usually GET request)

  - Extract dynamic parameters
- Perform Login (usually POST request), provide credentials and dynamic parameters extracted from the previous request

  - Extract dynamic parameters
- Open Home Page (usually GET request)
- etc.

You can extract dynamic parameters using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Also make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie based authentication.

---

BTW, you can quickly build test plan "skeleton" by simply recording your test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)